# XPage - How to get the right value of a check box group?

Tags: checkbox, xpages

In my simple XPage I have a check box group with formula items:

```
document1.getValue("cHumanNames") + "|" + document1.getValue("cUserID")
```

The lists `cHumanNames` and `cUserID` are ok, so I see and check `John Smith` and submit `john234`. As needed.

I was asked to display in a separate list the checked names (for control...) and it seems I can't come back from the `userID`. There must be a way to choose the value used for display:

```
getcomponent("checkBoxGroup1").??????
```

Of course, if I use `getValue()`, I get the list of the IDs, but I need the names. Where is that value?

Comment: You want the values in server-side or client-side JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify this XSnippet to search for the label of your alias value:

http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=get-selectable-values-of-a-component

Or you can use the index of the variables to find the correct label for your value (stored in the document.)

Answer (score 1):

When you look at the generated HTML source for checkbox group you would find something like this:

`<label><input name="view:_id1:checkBoxGroup1" value="john234" type="checkbox"> John Smith</input></label>`

Basically the label `John Smith` never gets submitted to the data source. If you are looking for SSJS implementation then Sven Hasselbach's answer would work. If you are looking for client-side JavaScript implementation then the below code snippet should work:

```
function getCheckedValues() {
    var checkedValues = new Array();
    dojo.query("input[name=\"#{id:checkBoxGroup1}\"]").forEach(
        function(node) {
            if (node.checked) {
                checkedValues.push(node.parentNode.innerText);
            }
        }
    );
    return checkedValues.join(", ");
}
```

The above snippet is written for checkbox group with name `checkBoxGroup1`.

Answer (score 0):

On server side there is no simple way to get display values - the selected value is kept only as the alias and the rest is used probably for rendering only. You can try to add additional layer of abstraction and create a map that will supply values for Your checkboxes and Your list. The list will simply use the map to translate checked values into display values.